# How to change values in a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a simple program to find the greater number of two numbers and store them in first line of an array.

the array is arr[tot][2] and I want to compare each element in arr[tot][0] to elements in arr[tot][1] but its giving me **Invalid array assignment**.
which function/method should I use to do that ?

```
for(i=0;i<tot;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i,1]>arr[i,0])
            {
            arr[i,0]=arr[i,1]}
    }
```

**Full program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //Input

    int tot = 23;
    int arr[tot][2] = {
    {9272992,-5268711},
    {-6457223,-8368810},
    {-3415057,-2776446},
    {-6492757,-3453386},
    {4313482,4783138},
    {5573672,8360909},
    {-2546018,2224083},
    {1267093,4700254},
    {6136723,9042717},
    {1277125,2796189},
    {-2062877,2036481},
    {6089545,-6182241},
    {-8795303,6074456},
    {8152425,785931},
    {-5134200,4319924},
    {6820437,-5861208},
    {9051213,-9636786},
    {-4230018,-4363843},
    {-2413233,-722776},
    {2182770,-8099750},
    {-5939638,-2243558},
    {-9738840,1514344},
    {9980524,1528253}
        };


    //the comparing
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<tot;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i,1]>arr[i,0])
                {
                arr[i,0]=arr[i,1]
                }
        }
    for(i=0;i<tot;i++)
        {
        cout<<arr[i,0]<<" ";
        }
    return 0;
}
```

**Thanks for answering my questions :)**
Also thanks for the downvotes, It really helped me understand that only smart and advanced questions are allowed here and stupid mistakes and syntax errors are not welcome.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: Try `arr[i][1]` and `arr[i][0]` instead.

Comment: Declaration of 2-D array. `int matrix[ROWS][COLS]`.

Comment: @rsp Its giving me too many initializers if I switch the rows and columns

Comment: @songtuanyao doesn't work, same error

Comment: Songtuanyao's answer is correct.  To access a single element, you need `arr[i][0]`, not `arr[i,0]`.  You have probably missed one of the cases.  Look at the error message more carefully.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yeah I worked, I was writing the wrong syntax. Thank you

Comment: @JatinderBrar Please don't feel discouraged by the downvotes. I upvoted your question to balance the downvotes. Actually I just knew the comma operator concept, when I was debugging your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@songyuanyao's comment is correct. If you want to access a value in a 2D array, you need to use `arr[i][0]`.

You code has three errors:

1. When you declare an array, the number of elements must be a constant. So `int tot = 23;` should be `const int tot = 23;`
2. `arr[i,0]` is a valid expression, but it shouldn't be used here. You should use the syntax `arr[i][0]` throughout this program.
3. You missed a semicolon.

Some explanation for #2: The error "Invalid array assignment" is due to the line `arr[i,0]=arr[i,1]` (you missed a `;` here as well). In `arr[i,0]`, the comma is a [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which returns the value of the second operand. So `arr[i,0]` is equivalent to `arr[0]`, which is a 1D array. Similarly `arr[i,1]` is `arr[1]` which is also a 1D array. But [array is not a modifiable L-value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx), so `arr[i,0]=arr[i,1]` gives "Invalid array assignment" error. This also explains why `arr[i,1]>arr[i,0]` doesn't give compile-time error, but it's a runtime bug.

Comment: yeah, I understand now. But I don't understand the constant function. It doesn't gives me any errors. I want to ask the user how many numbers they want to enter. I am not going to change that. Does constant stops me from changing that number if I make a mistake ?

Answer (score -2):

Do not use this syntax

```
 if(arr[i,1]>arr[i,0])
  {
    arr[i,0]=arr[i,1]
  }
```

Instead, try using this :

```
 if(arr[i][1]>arr[i][0])
   {
      arr[i][0]=arr[i][1]
   }
```